# How to shorten my function?

Tags: php, function

I have a function to calculate price as below. Im just interested to learn any other way to shorten my code.

**PHP**

```
function calculate_price( $quantity, $target_quantity, $price, $rate )
{
    $total = 0;

    if( $quantity > $target_quantity )
    {
        $total = $target_quantity * $price;
        $quantity -= $target_quantity;

        $tmp_price = $price;
        do {
            $tmp_price = $tmp_price * $rate;
            $total += $tmp_price;
            $quantity--;
        } while( $quantity > 0 );

    }
    else
    {
        $total = $quantity*$price;
    }

    return $total;

}

echo calculate_price( 8, 5, 3, 0.5 );
```

Comment: this look perfect i think

Comment: "shorter" does not equal to "better".

Comment: this is a good function realized in php, keep it as it is. the code is very clear, you can also use another way by a recursive function but i think not necessary.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead of shortening it, I would rather suggest to add some comments =)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the decrement in the `while` statement.

```
while( --$quantity > 0 );
```

Comment: That is a terrible idea, the next one to read this is totally going to miss this. I would down vote, if the OP did not ask for shortening. But shortening does not equal better or a good idea.